# What is the procedural way to arrange lex and parse files?

Tags: compiler-construction

I searched quite a bit, and still can't seem to grasp the work flow, and file arranging of tokens, the lexer, and the parser. I'm using plain C with Visual Studio. Went through countless tutorials, and they seem to skip this part.

So when you write a simple function in the source.txt, the lexer is in a `C` file, reads the source file, and breaks the simple function into tokens?

In  Dr. Dobbs book, there is a file that contains a list of already defined tokens that is written into a def file, if the previous question is true, where does this predefined token list fit in?

Once the source file is read by `lex`, and the tokens are split,  how does the parser retrieve the tokenized info `lex` is putting out, and then make the grammar?

I've seen typedef struct used for what seemed like a slight breakdown of predefined tokens, and somewhat of the lex inside. So are the tokens in 1 file, the lex in 1, and the parser in 1? Or the tokens in 1 but lex and parse together calling that token file?

I just need clarification, a good point in the right direction,  any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Don't read only "tutorials", read *books*, learn the *theory* (discrete math), and read some source for existing (and **simple**) compilers, translators and interpreters. And as with everything in the programming world, there's no one single true way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple classic way to organize these tasks is by setting the various parts up as subroutines passing datastructures to one another.  Forgive my sloppy syntax.

First you need a definitino of a token, produced by the lexer.  This is almost always a struct with an enum to indicate which token type, and a union type to carry any value the token type may have:

```
 struct Token {
     enum  // distinguishes token types
          { EndOfFile, Integer, String, Float, Identifier
            Semicolon, Colon, Plus, Minus, Times, Divide, LefParen, RightParen,
            KeywordBegin, KeywordDeclare, KeywordEnd, ...
          } tokentype
      union {
         long numeric_value; // holds numeric value of integer-valued token
         char* string_value; // holds ptr to string body of identifiers or string literals
         float float_value; // holds numeric value of floating-point valued token
            } tokenvalue
      }
```

You'll want to build an abstract syntax tree.  For that you'll need a TreeNode type.
Like Tokens, these are almost always an enum to indicate which node type, and a union to hold various properties of the node type, and finally a list of pointers to children:

```
      struct TreeNode {
          enum // distiguishes tree node types
             { Goal, Function, StatementList, Statement, LeftHandSide, Expression,
               Add, Subtract, Times, Divide, Identifier, FunctionCall, ...
             } nodetype
          children* TreeNode[4];  // a small constant here is almost always enough
          union // hold values specific to node type, often includes a copy of lexer union
             { long numeric_value; // holds:
                       // numeric value of integer-valued token
                       // index of built-in function number
                       // actual number of children if it varies
                       // ...
               char* string_value; // holds ptr to string body of identifiers or string literals
               float float_value; // holds numeric value of floating-point valued token
            } nodevalue
        }
```

MyCompiler.c contains the following code:

```
     int main() {
            filehandle Handle = OpenSourceFile(&FileName);
            ASTrootnode TreeNode = Parser(Handle);
            CodeGenerator(ASTrootnode);
            exit();
     }
```

Parser.c contains the following code:

```
     TreeNode Parser(filehandle Handle) {
            <parsingmachinery>
            nexttoken Token=Lexer(filehandle);
            <moreparsingmachinery to build tree nodes>
            return toplevel_TreeNode;
     }
```

Lexer.c contains the following code:

```
    Token Lexer(filehandle Handle) {
         token Token;
         <process characters in buffer>
         if bufferp=end_of_buffer
            fileread(filehandle,&bufferbody,bufferlength);
         <process characters in buffer>
         token.tokentype=<typeofrecognizedtoken>
         token.tokenvalue.long=<valueofnumerictoken>
         ...
         return Token;
    }
```

You'll obviously want to put the Token and TreeNode declarations into header files that can be shared across your compiler source files.

If you build a high-performance compiler, you'll want to optimize these routines.  One trivial example:  the FileHandle can become a global variable, and thus need not be passed between the pieces as an explicit argument.  One not so trivial example: you'll want to a high-performance lexer generator, or hand-code the lexer, to maximize its character processing rate, especially at skipping blanks and comments.

If you want to see specific details on how to construct a parser that builds ASTs, see my SO answer on building recursive descent parsers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it more fully.  I appreciate it alot. Its been weeks of going through web pages, and books available. I am excited!!! Repumped now.

Comment: If you like my answer, you can upvote it.  If you really like it, you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Lol, I thought I did accept answer. Not enough rep points to upvote. You know any good sources to help learn the struct part?

Comment: Sounds to me like you haven't had a data structures class.Without that, you're not going to go very far in building a compiler.  I suggest you get a book and read it, hard: https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms-third-edition

Comment: I have a few. Just havent made it that far into them yet. Thanks man. You have been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the second example and understanding you cite is quite typical with one adjustment.

Yes, the pre-defined token list (usually in an enum if allowed) exist in header or similar. And both the lex and parser can reference that header file.

But the tokens actually ***discovered*** by the 'lex' are passed on to the parser at execution time.